# Django user authentication does not work, how can I fix my login?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-login

I am using the django-email-verification app and I had to change how a User is signed up but I left the login authentication part the same. Every time I try to login it does not allow me to sign in and says that the credentials are wrong. Also I used emails as usernames.  I'm thinking its the:
`user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])`
that needs to be changed. Please how do I fix the login?

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django_email_verification import sendConfirm


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['pass1'] == request.POST['pass2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
                return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error': 'Email is already registered'})
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                '''user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['pass1'])
                auth.login(request, user)'''
                user = get_user_model().objects.create(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['pass1'], email=request.POST['username'])
                sendConfirm(user)
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error': 'Passwords must match'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html',{'error':'username or password is incorrect.'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with authenticating, but with *creating* the user. Passwords are normally *hashed*. The [**`.create(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create) will *not* hash these, you can make use of [**`.create_user(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) instead:

```
user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
    username=request.POST['username'],
    password=request.POST['pass1'],
    email=request.POST['username']
)
```

The `.create_user(…)` function is a function the manager of the user model normally should provide. This will for (most) user models store the *hash* of the password in the database.

Comment: I used ```user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], 
password=request.POST['pass1']) auth.login(request, user)```                                                          and it worked fine, but for django-email-verification I need to use the get_user_model.

Comment: @RafaelAkopian: you still *can* use `get_user_model`. But a user model, even a custom one, needs to implement a *user manager*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model this offers a `create_user` method.

Comment: @RafaelAkopian: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#password-management-in-django on how Django stores passwords.